# Single column Date table issue:Groovy:Date variable '_' needs to be declared as method parameter

Tags: spock, data-driven-tests

I have a very simple test as blow:

```
def "setContent_activity_finished"(Status editStatus) {
    // Variables.........................

    given:
    activity.getStatus() >> editStatus.toString()

    when:
    handler.setContent(activityId,jsonString)

    then:
    0*view.appendPossible(_)

    where:
    editStatus       |_
    FINISHED         |_
    CANCELED         |_
}
```

According to the document http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_driven_testing.html 
Data tables must have at least two columns. A single-column table can be written as:

```
where:
a | _
1 | _
7 | _
0 | _
```

And I follow this rule,but got an error look like picture shown:

```
Groovy:Date variable '_' needs to be declared as method parameter
```

[image]

so,please tell me What the problem is here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter list has to be either `()` or `(Status editStatus, _)`. (You can't declare just one data variable but not the other.) There is an open pull request to allow `(Status editStatus)` in this particular case.

Comment: In recent snapshots, `(Status editStatus)` is supported.

Answer (score 18):

Another way to achieve single column is to use data pipes
http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

```
where:
editStatus << [FINISHED, CANCELED]
```